# Extract Url from access Log in Splunk

Tags: extract, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

This is the sample accessLog which is coming up in the Splunk ui.

1. `{"timestamp":"2021-10-17T15:03:56,763Z","level":"INFO","thread":"reactor-http-epolpl-20","message":"method=GET, uri=/api/v1/hello1, status=200, duration=1, "logger":"reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog"}`
2. `{"timestamp":"2021-10-17T15:03:56,763Z","level":"INFO","thread":"reactor-http-epolpl-20","message":"method=GET, uri=/api/v1/dummy1, status=200, duration=1, "logger":"reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog"}`

I want to extract the url and make a count for all the API's like how many times an API is hitted from the uri part(uri=/api/v1/dummy1)

```
(index=dummy OR index=dummy1) source=*dummy-service*  logger=reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog 
| rex field=message "(?<url>uri.[\/api\/v1\/hello]+)" 
| chart count by url
```

But it's not giving URL in a proper format. I tried various regex, but couldn't get the proper URL count.

I wanted to use this query to show the API counts in the Splunk dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be with the regular expression in the `rex` command.  Square brackets (`[]`) in a regex denote a set from which any character can match, in any order.  The example regex should match "/api/v1/hello", but also will match "iap/1v/ohell", "philo", and any other permutation of those characters.  It will not, however, match "/api/v1/dummy1".

Try this query.  The `rex` command here takes everything between "uri=" and the following comma as the url.

```
index=dummy OR index=dummy1  source=*dummy-service*  logger=reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog 
| rex field=message "uri=(?<url>[^,]+)" 
| chart count by url
```

Comment: Yeah, Actually first I tried with this approach only, but problem came when There is a GET request with input params as path variables. So for every different input param it was considering a separate url.  Like for /api/v1/hello/123  && /api/v1/hello/456 it was considering it as a separate url.

So now I used eval expression like this to overcome the above situation. 

eval url=replace(url,"\d+","-")